# Trying to redirect after form submit... cant change header Error

Tags: php, email, redirect, header, phpmailer

I've made a form file, where user can upload files with phpmailer. Everything is working fine...except i cant redirect. I know many people have asked this question before and i've really tried following all solutions provided, but I'm still stuck...
this is my php file that handles the form and I want it to redirect to my php/smarty file where the form itself is..

```
<?php
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

 require_once "../klassen/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php";
 require_once "../klassen/phpmailer/SMTP.php";
 require_once "../klassen/phpmailer/Exception.php";


if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $lname = $_POST['lname'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $phone = $_POST['phone'];
         $msg = $_POST['msg'];

         $mail = new PHPMailer();

         //smtp settings
         $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
         $mail->isSMTP();
         $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
         $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
         $mail->Username = "somemailadress";
         $mail->Password = "password";
         $mail->Port = 587;
         $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

         //email settings

         $mail->isHTML(true);
         $mail->setFrom($email);
         $mail->addAddress("blabla@gmail.com");
         $mail->subject = "$email ($name)";
         $mail->Body =

             $name .

             $email .

             $msg
          ;
         $mail->AltBody =
             ' This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';


         if (!empty($_FILES['attach'])) {
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['attach']['name']); $i++) {
                 $mail->addAttachment(
                     $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$i],
                     $_FILES['attach']['name'][$i]
                 );
             }
         }

         if ($mail->send()) {
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


flush();
header('Location:  vacatures2.php');
    die('should have redirected by now');




         }
         else {
             echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
         }
     }
```

Im getting following error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testarrays/scripts/contact.php on line 61
should have redirected by now

There s no indicator where it goes wrong, only that it fails at line 61 right?
Could the problem be with the php file its redirecting to?

Please help

Comment: `flush();` will send buffer to browser, so you face to `headers already sent in`

Comment: I tried that for error report, but same thing without...

Comment: There is something already sent (an `echo`, some space before `<?php`, ...). You should check the output source.

Comment: The way you're handling uploaded files is unsafe. Please refer to the PHP and PHPMailer docs & examples for how to handle them correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure Syscall? I checked for  blank spaces before or after, didnt find any. Ive tried to check for UTF8 BOM :p, I cant find anything that s mentioned in the other questions? Does it have to do with the smarty template im using to make my other page where the form is located?

Comment: i could quickly try checking that by making the form in a new php file and see what happens.... brb. I just tried..thats not it:/